# Android animation garbage collection issue

Tags: java, android, animation, garbage-collection

- I have an `arraylist of AnimationDrawables` in android with each
  element in it corresponding to a particular animation. Each animation
  happens on click of a particular button.
- Synchronously adding frames to the animation(on button click) results
  in slow responsiveness of the application. So I thought of using an
  asynctask to fetch frames for me and it works fine for the first time
  I load the activity.
- The second time it is very slow i.e the animations appear after a
  long time. If I somehow try to cache the animation (by making the
  animation object static), it works well for 2 or 3 times but then
  slows again.
- For android ice cream sandwich : I have also used
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true" in the
  manifest file.  The memory seems to be an issue. At a time about
  500Kb memory is required for each animation.

Can someone please suggest an alternative ? 
I know forcing garbage is not possible. So what esle i could do?

Comment: This depend on how you are doing the animation. Also, are you constantly loading and unloading data? 500k might not be too bad if you manage things well. How large are the images?

Comment: @Joe : I am using frames for each animation.Constantly loading and unloading ? I am not pretty sure what you meant by that but yes Once each animation is finished(in an activity), I set its data to null using the arraylist.set(index,null) method. The problem occurs when i leave the activity and come again to it. Its because the dangling pointers to these null blocks are not garbage collected.